# None result in the grouped method in Python coding

Tags: python, function, nlp

I am trying to get result as a printed sentence in my NER code:

> [(Token_1, PoS_1, Tag_1), ..., (Token_n, PoS_n, Tag_n)]

In the function 'get_next' I am getting '*None*' result every time - not sure what I am doing wrong here. Code:

```
class SentenceGetter(object):

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.n_sent = 1    
        self.data = data
        self.empty = False
        agg_func = lambda s: [(w, p, t) for w, p, t in zip(s["Lemat"].values.tolist(),
                                                           s["POS"].values.tolist(),
                                                           s["TAG"].values.tolist())]
        self.grouped = self.data.groupby("Forma").apply(agg_func)
        self.sentences = [s for s in self.grouped]
    
    def get_next(self):
        try:
            s = self.grouped["Forma: {}".format(self.n_sent)]
            self.n_sent += 1
            return s
        except:
            return None
        
getter = SentenceGetter(data)
sent = getter.get_next()
print('Example sentence:')
print(sent)
```

Code block about definition:

```
data = pd.read_csv("nkjp-morph-named.txt",delimiter="\t")
data = data.fillna(method="ffill")

print("Form number: ", len(data.groupby(['Forma'])))

lemats = list(set(data["Lemat"].values))
n_lemats = len(lemats)
print("Lemats: ", n_lemats)

tags = list(set(data["TAG"].values))
print("TAG:", tags)
n_tags = len(tags)
print("Number of TAGs: ", n_tags)

print("Dataset:")
data.head(n=16)
```

Could you please help me to understand it more why its None still??
Excepted result:

> Example sentence: [('Thousands', 'NNS', 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'),
> ('demonstrators', 'NNS', 'O'), ('have', 'VBP', 'O'), ('marched',
> 'VBN', 'O'), ('through', 'IN', 'O'), ('London', 'NNP', 'B-geo'),
> ('to', 'TO', 'O'), ('protest', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('war',
> 'NN', 'O'), ('in', 'IN', 'O'), ('Iraq', 'NNP', 'B-geo'), ('and', 'CC',
> 'O'), ('demand', 'VB', 'O'), ('the', 'DT', 'O'), ('withdrawal', 'NN',
> 'O'), ('of', 'IN', 'O'), ('British', 'JJ', 'B-gpe'), ('troops', 'NNS',
> 'O'), ('from', 'IN', 'O'), ('that', 'DT', 'O'), ('country', 'NN',
> 'O'), ('.', '.', 'O')]

Comment: What are you expecting `"Forma: {}".format(self.n_sent)` to do?

Comment: I expect that it will be grouped according to appropriate sentences, an example is given at the end of the description as a one sentence - let's say that column Forma is the first column where we have row like "Sentence1"

Comment: I suspect its throwing an error. Remove the `try... except` structure & see if its throwing an error.

Comment: Ok I found the main issue here - in the file I imported the first column had a space character between the next column and not a tab character after displaying the data structure it turned out